# Remove d3 Viz on Selection of New Source File

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have JavaScript code referencing a PHP drop-down (s1):

```
var dropdown = d3.select("#s1")
var change = function() {
var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

d3.json(source, function(graph) {
    //Do stuff
})
}

dropdown.on("change", change)
change();
```

Currently, on selection of an option in the drop-down, the correct viz appears, but it overlays any previous selections.

I tried adding `d3.select("svg > *").remove()` in various places in the code above, to no avail.

What do I need to add to remove the previous d3 viz when a selection is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that needed to be done was change `d3.select("svg > *").remove()` to `d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove()` and place it on the first line of the `change()` function.